# Driverless AI : Python pipeline not getting created

Tags: python-3.x, driverless-ai

I have DAI 1.5.1 version installed on my system. I executed an experiment and it ran successfully, but while creating Python pipeline I am getting following error.
please help me understand why it is not getting created ?

2019-01-28 05:05:11,936 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Creating scoring pipeline named scoring_h2oai_experiment_cakifafu
2019-01-28 05:05:11,944 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 WARNING: Scoring pipeline already exists at /opt/app/workload/deployments/h2o-ai/dai-1.5.1/tmp/h2oai_experiment_cakifafu/scoring_pipeline
2019-01-28 05:05:11,947 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 WARNING: Clobbering existing scoring pipeline...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,008 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Creating thrift IDL...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,013 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Collecting wheels...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,017 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing requirements.txt...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,021 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing environment.yml...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,024 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing example.py...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,028 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing http_server.py...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,032 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing tcp_server.py...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,035 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing setup.py...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,038 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing example_client.py
2019-01-28 05:05:12,042 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Writing run_http_client.sh
2019-01-28 05:05:12,080 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 47125 INFO : Building scoring wheel...
2019-01-28 05:05:12,386 C: D:159.6GB M:114.9GB 94411 ERROR : Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "h2oaicore/scoring.py", line 799, in h2oaicore.scoring.do_build_scoring_pipeline
          File "h2oaicore/scoring.py", line 578, in h2oaicore.scoring.build_scoring_pipeline
    RuntimeError: Scoring module wheel build failed: b"Copying pipeline...\nCopying modeling pipeline...\nCopying schema...\nCopying config overrides...\nCopying model summary...\nCopying dependency wheels...\nCopying scorer wheel assets...\nUsing python executable located at /opt/app/workload/deployments/h2o-ai/dai-1.5.1/python/bin/python\n/opt/app/workload/deployments/h2o-ai/dai-1.5.1/python/bin/python: symbolic link to `python3.6'\nPython 3.6.4\nSetting up virtualenv...\nbuild.sh: /opt/app/workload/deployments/h2o-ai/dai-1.5.1/python/bin/virtualenv: /opt/app/workload/deployments/h2o-ai/dai-1.5.1-linux-x86_64/python/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory\n"

Comment: aand your question is?

Comment: @Sugato - Post updated. please check.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend not trying to compile it yourself.

The easiest thing to do is install a second DAI environment and use the provided fully self-contained python that comes with it.

See the relevant instructions cut-and-pasted from the docs below:

——

Running the Python Scoring Pipeline - Recommended

1. Download the TAR SH version of Driverless AI from https://www.h2o.ai/download/ (for either Linux or IBM Power).
2. Use bash to execute the download. This creates a new dai-nnn folder.
3. Change directories into the new Driverless AI folder.

   cd dai-nnn directory.
   ￼
4. Run the following to install the Python Scoring Pipeline for your completed Driverless AI experiment:

   ./dai-env.sh pip install /path/to/your/scoring_experiment.whl
   ￼
5. Run the following command to run the included scoring pipeline example:

   DRIVERLESS_AI_LICENSE_KEY="pastekeyhere" SCORING_PIPELINE_INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES=0 ./dai-env.sh /path/to/your/run_example.sh
   ￼